# Python's os.path choking on Hebrew filenames

Tags: python, internationalization, hebrew

I'm writing a script that has to move some file around, but unfortunately it doesn't seem `os.path` plays with internationalization very well. When I have files named in Hebrew, there are problems. Here's a screenshot of the contents of a directory:

[image]
<sub>(source: [thegreenplace.net](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/temp/hebfilenameshot.png))</sub>

Now consider this code that goes over the files in this directory:

```
files = os.listdir('test_source')

for f in files:
    pf = os.path.join('test_source', f)
    print pf, os.path.exists(pf)
```

The output is:

```
test_source\ex True
test_source\joe True
test_source\mie.txt True
test_source\__()'''.txt True
test_source\????.txt False
```

Notice how `os.path.exists` thinks that the hebrew-named file doesn't even exist?
How can I fix this?

ActivePython 2.5.2 on Windows XP Home SP2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hmm, after [some digging](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/unicode) it appears that when supplying os.listdir a unicode string, this kinda works:

```
files = os.listdir(u'test_source')

for f in files:

    pf = os.path.join(u'test_source', f)
    print pf.encode('ascii', 'replace'), os.path.exists(pf)
```

===>

```
test_source\ex True
test_source\joe True
test_source\mie.txt True
test_source\__()'''.txt True
test_source\????.txt True
```

Some important observations here:

- Windows XP (like all NT derivatives) stores *all* filenames in unicode
- `os.listdir` (and similar functions, like `os.walk`) should be passed a unicode string in order to work correctly with unicode paths. Here's a quote from the aforementioned link:

> os.listdir(), which returns filenames,
>   raises an issue: should it return the
>   Unicode version of filenames, or
>   should it return 8-bit strings
>   containing the encoded versions?
>   os.listdir() will do both, depending
>   on whether you provided the directory
>   path as an 8-bit string or a Unicode
>   string. If you pass a Unicode string
>   as the path, filenames will be decoded
>   using the filesystem's encoding and a
>   list of Unicode strings will be
>   returned, while passing an 8-bit path
>   will return the 8-bit versions of the
>   filenames.

- And lastly, `print` wants an ascii string, not unicode, so the path has to be encoded to ascii.

Comment: print doesn't seem to be picky about ascii on all environments though. See my answer.

Comment: print has no problem in printing unicode: the problem may be in the stdout encoding. If the console is unicode there is no problem, otherwise an explicit encode is required.

Comment: That's excellent. Should mean that you can report sane file names on Windows to if you print to a file handle with the right encoding set. The 'replace' error handler just signals defeat to me. =)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a Unicode vs ASCII issue - `os.listdir` is returning a list of ASCII strings.

Edit: I tried it on Python 3.0, also on XP SP2, and `os.listdir` simply omitted the Hebrew filenames instead of listing them at all.

According to the docs, this means it was unable to decode it:

> Note that when os.listdir() returns a
>   list of strings, filenames that cannot
>   be decoded properly are omitted rather
>   than raising UnicodeError.

Comment: I guess I could try, but it won't help me as I can't move to 3.0 at the moment. I'm sure there should be a solution for 2.5

Answer (score 1):

It works like a charm using Python 2.5.1 on OS X:

```
subdir/bar.txt True
subdir/foo.txt True
subdir/עִבְרִית.txt True
```

Maybe that means that this has to do with Windows XP somehow?

EDIT: I also tried with unicode strings to try mimic the Windows behaviour better:

```
for f in os.listdir(u'subdir'):
  pf = os.path.join(u'subdir', f)
  print pf, os.path.exists(pf)

subdir/bar.txt True
subdir/foo.txt True
subdir/עִבְרִית.txt True
```

In the Terminal (os x stock command prompt app) that is. Using IDLE it still worked but didn't print the filename correctly. To make sure it really is unicode there I checked:

```
>>>os.listdir(u'listdir')[2]
u'\u05e2\u05b4\u05d1\u05b0\u05e8\u05b4\u05d9\u05ea.txt'
```

Comment: i think it has to do with the fact that Windows stores all filenames in Unicode. see my own partial answer

Comment: curious. if I just pass pf to print, it throws an encoding exception. it must be expecting ascii

Comment: I think piro has it nailed down (in the comment to another answer on this question). It's the encoding of stdout.

Answer (score 0):

A question mark is the more or less universal symbol displayed when a unicode character can't be represented in a specific encoding.  Your terminal or interactive session under Windows is probably using ASCII or ISO-8859-1 or something.  So the actual string is unicode, but it gets translated to ???? when printed to the terminal.  That's why it works for PEZ, using OSX.

Comment: can I make the windoze terminal display unicode? what does OSX do to show it nicely?